# Testcafe - run ClientFunction code on iframe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to access a public object available on an iframe scope but the code that I'm running on the ClientFunction gets executed on the parent, I managed to get it working using the `--disable-web-security` flag and accesing the frame like this `window.frames['0'].store`. (Not happy with that hack TBH)

But now looks like TestCafe updated to some newer version of Chromium and there's a message telling me that the flag is not allowed anymore.

Is there any way to run client code targetting a specific iframe without needing that nasty flag?

Answer (score 2):

To run `ClientFunction` on an iframe, you need to switch to it beforehand.

```js
const fn = ClientFunction(() => true);

test('test', async t => {
    await t.switchToIframe('#iframe');

    await fn();

});
```

Comment: It miserably fails because the iframe is inside a shadow root element.

Comment: You are right, the `--disable-web-security` usage looks like a hack in this instance. The `switchToIframe` method is an official way to work with iframes in TestCafe. Unfortunately, we cannot propose a reliable workaround for iframes inside shadow DOM. We have a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3673) regarding shadow DOM iframes. Please subscribe to this issue to keep track of our progress on this functionality.

Comment: In v1.20.1, you can now switch to iframes in shadow roots